# JNA - C++ Shared Library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, jna, jnaerator

I have a project consisting of various headers and .cpp files. With this I built a shared library with Eclipse and everything is ok. Now I want to use JNA with this C++ library. I am aware of other (maybe easier) options than JNA but it is obligatory to use this. I have searched around the web but to be honest I have not found until now a quite easy example to understand what I have to do and go on. I have tested some examples but they only consist of one header and one .cpp with very small functions and are not helpful for me at all. I have also found a tool called JNAerator which is supposed to simplify the procedure (if I understand well at least) but also the examples for it are limited. So I would really appreciate it if someone could explain me the steps to do this I want (C++ shared library with many headers and .cpp ---> JNA) and/or provide me links with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough you did mention JNA is mandatory, did you consider using [bridj](https://code.google.com/p/bridj), [javacpp](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) or  [swig](http://www.swig.org/)?

If you really insist of using JNA then you have to hand-write C interfaces to the C++ API.
Some examples I found: [(1)](http://m-hewedy.blogspot.de/2011/08/java-native-access-jna-by-example.html), [(2)](http://desmontandojava.blogspot.de/2013/09/groovy-and-c-through-jna.html), [(3)](http://www.viaboxxsystems.de/java-interoperation-with-a-native-dll-using-jna), [(4)](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077513/learn-java/java-tip-17--integrating-java-with-c--.html) (google is endless ;-). For specific questions you may also try the [jna user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jna-users).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes unfortunately I must use JNA. Can I use jnaerator instead of doing the work by hand? I mean jnaerator is supposed to do the same job (creating Java interfaces from C/C++ files) or I am wrong?
Thanks again!

Comment: Yes JNA has limited c++ support. For specific details I would ask the jna forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jna-users

Comment: Ok I will ask there for any more help. Thanks!

Comment: JNAerator can generate *some* C++ mappings for you.  While JNA is capable of creating objects and invoking C++ methods, you need JNAerator or similar tool to figure out the name mangling and virtual table offsets for you.